# Enter Beg End parameters automatically in Evil-Visual-Mode

Tags: elisp, spacemacs

I see some functions like evil-change or evil-delete are take in the beginning and end of a visual region in evil-visual-state.
I've looked at the source code in "evil-commands.el" of these functions but their 'beg' and 'end' parameters just seem to come out of nowhere. And some (such as the one below) aren't even interactive.

Why this is and how I can do the same thing in my own methods?

Below is just an example of one of the methods I looked at:

```
;; Defined in ~/.emacs.d/elpa/evil-20170712.2350/evil-commands.el
(evil-define-operator evil-invert-char (beg end type)
  "Invert case of character."
  :motion evil-forward-char
  (if (eq type 'block)
      (evil-apply-on-block #'evil-invert-case beg end nil)
    (evil-invert-case beg end)
    (when evil-this-motion
      (goto-char end)
      (when (and evil-cross-lines
                 evil-move-cursor-back
                 (not evil-move-beyond-eol)
                 (not (evil-visual-state-p))
                 (not (evil-operator-state-p))
                 (eolp) (not (eobp)) (not (bolp)))
        (forward-char)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evil-invert-char` is not defined using a regular `defun`, but using the macro `evil-define-operator`, which can be found in `evil-macros.el`. Using `M-x describe-function RET evil-define-operator RET`:

```
evil-define-operator is a Lisp macro in ‘evil-macros.el’.

(evil-define-operator OPERATOR (BEG END ARGS...) DOC [[KEY VALUE]...] BODY...)

Define an operator command OPERATOR.
```

You can use the excellent `macrostep` mode (which is bound to `, d m` in my Spacemacs, when in `emacs-lisp-mode`) to expand `evil-define-operator`. The first expansion will rewrite the `evil-define-operator`-macro into an `evil-define-command`-macro, which includes a call to `interactive`. As this macroexpansion is done by the elisp interpreter or before byte compilation, the variables `BEG` and `END` can be assigned using the `interactive` call inserted by the macro.