# How to reverse a string selected in evil visual mode?

Tags: string, emacs

I'm using Spacemacs, trying to write a function to reverse the string selected in evil visual mode. Here's what I get so far:

```
(defun fengqi/string-reverse (beg end)
  (interactive)
  (let ((string-to-reverse (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (message string-to-reverse beg end))
    ;; (delete-region beg end)
    ;; (insert (string-reverse string-to-reverse))
  )
```

Obviously it doesn't work. How do I

1. get the selected region?
2. replace it with what I want?

I have read [Enter Beg End parameters automatically in Evil-Visual-Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227566/enter-beg-end-parameters-automatically-in-evil-visual-mode), it's helpful, but I still don't how to do it.

---

To answer some questions in the comment:

When I was searching for some solutions, in [this blog](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/02/02/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-new-string-manipulation-functions/) I found the function `string-reverse`. I tried in `*ielm*` buffer and it worked.

What I want is a function to **reverse the string selected in evil visual mode**.

Comment: Did you define a function `string-reverse`? It's not defined in Emacs 25.2 (`emacs -Q`), as far as I can see. What do you mean by "obviously it doesn't work"? Specify what you mean by "doesn't work" - what does it do vs what you expected it to do?

Comment: @Drew string-reverse is an alias for ‘reverse’ in ‘subr-x.el’.
(string-reverse SEQ)
This function is obsolete since 25.1; use ‘reverse’ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made some progress, and still there's some problem need to tackle.

1. The text selected in evil visual mode actually don't seem to be different from native emacs selections. What I missed is to pass the right [code character](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes) to `interactive`, which should be `r`.
2. According to [this blog](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_find_replace_text.html), I now use `search-forward` and `replace-match` to replace the string.

And now the function looks like this:

```
(defun fengqi/string-reverse (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region beg end)
    (let ((string-to-reverse (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
      (message string-to-reverse)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward string-to-reverse)
      (replace-match (string-reverse string-to-reverse)))))
```

But there's still a bug I don't know the reason. When the first character of the selected text is in upper case, this function doesn't work well:

For `Abcde` I expect the result to be `edcbA`, but instead I get `EdcbA`, which I don't see why.

Comment: No idea why such a bug should result form that code. But the blog mentioned has "Invert case of character." Maybe something went into your way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implemention:

```
    (defun ar-reverse-at-point (&optional beg end)
  "Replace a string or region at point by result of ‘reverse’.

Works at any string detected at position, unless
optional BEG as start and
optional END as end are given as arguments or
an active region is set deliberately"
  (interactive "*")
  (let* ((pps (parse-partial-sexp (point-min) (point)))
     ;; (save-excursion (cadr (ar-beginning-of-string-atpt)))
     (beg (cond (beg)
            ((use-region-p)
             (region-beginning))
            ((and (nth 8 pps)(nth 3 pps))
             (goto-char (nth 8 pps))
             (point))))
     ;; (copy-marker (cdr (ar-end-of-string-atpt)))
     (end (cond (end)
            ((use-region-p)
             (copy-marker (region-end)))
            ((and (nth 8 pps)(nth 3 pps))
             (forward-sexp)
             (copy-marker (point)))))
     (erg (buffer-substring beg end)))
    (when (and beg end)
      (delete-region beg end)
      (insert (reverse erg)))))
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my solution, and give me some suggestions for the bug I mentioned? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @fengqi Defining the region via interactive "r" needs some attention. Emacs knows from syntax the border of a string - see ‘parse-partial-sexp’. Just hand it over to ‘reverse’. Finally replace the buffer-substring from known positions.